# passing a variable from php to bash script file using popen

Tags: php, bash

In my php file, this is how i run a bash script file.

```
$run=popen("/var/www/html/work/bashfile.sh","r");
```

and inside bashfile.sh i have something like this

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/work/prepare
./runfile 0.3 180 username
```

This code works perfect by producing pictures in order username1.jpg, username2.jpg

But when i try to do the same thin by passing variable to the bash script using php it does nor work and this is how i was writing the code
 In my php file

```
$vari="name1";
$run=popen("/var/www/html/work/bashfile2.sh $vari","r");
```

and inside my bashfile2.sh  i do

```
#! /bin/bash
$vari=$1
    cd /var/www/html/work/prepare
    ./runfile 0.3  180 $vari
```

But this is not working. Please any idea how to work things around to end up getting the results of the first code

Answer (score 0):

popen() is interpreting your variable as a part of the string you send. Try using {} to enclose your variable when using them directly in strings.

```
$vari = "name1";
$run = popen("/var/www/html/work/bashfile2.sh {$vari}","r");
```

Comment: yhh. i think maybe doing ./runfile 0.3  180 $vari is not the right thing in thr bash script